# How to flash Magisk-x.y.z.zip using fastboot without using TWRP?

Tags: fastboot

Is it mandatory to use twrp to flash Magisk. Can it be flashed using **fastboot**

Comment: you probably can't flash magisk with fastboot
you must have twrp installed or any other custom recovery..
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant **fastboot** mode.

And no, Magisk cannot be flashed using Fastboot mode. It is a zip file and not an image file that you can just flash to a partition.  If you want to use fastboot, you should consider patching your boot image using Magisk Manager and then boot that image using fastboot boot command.

```
fastboot boot magisk-patched.img
```

Or if you are sure you have the correct boot image, you can flash the patched image too:

```
fastboot flash boot magisk-patched.img
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed typo. Magisk Manager is a apk file. How to use Magsik Manager to rewrite the boot image on a non-rooted phone while i am trying to root the mobile using Magisk.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit [this way](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#boot-image-patching)

Comment: You need the stock boot image. Then you can use Magisk Manager to inject Magisk into the boot image. And then flash/boot the image which will load magisk init commands when the device starts up.